# The array is static, but the array size isn't know until runtime. How is this possible?

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic-memory-allocation, dynamic-arrays

This has been troubling me for a while. It goes to the heart of my (lack of) understanding of the difference between static and dynamic memory allocation. The following array is an ordinary static array, which should mean the memory is allocated during compile time, correct? Yet, I've set it up so that the user enters the array size at runtime.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  cout << "how many elements should the array hold? ";
  int arraySize;
  cin >> arraySize;

  int arr[arraySize];

  for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; ++i)
    arr[i] = i * 2;

  return 0;
}
```

Note that there are no `new` or `delete` operators in this program. It works fine in Xcode 4.2 (default Clang compiler) as well as my school's UNIX server (GCC 4.4.5). How does the compiler know how much memory to allocate for `arr` when the array is created at compile time? Is this just a fluke of my compiler, dangerous code that could corrupt other memory, or is this legit?

Comment: This uses a feature called _variable-length arrays_, which debuted in C99.

Comment: Try compiling with `g++ -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c++98`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a non-standard extension of your C++ compilers. Note that in C, unlike in C++, this is officially supported (i.e. standard-mandated behaviour) since C99. In C++, it is not supported because there's already a solution to the problem: Use `std::vector` instead of the array.

Not however that the array is *not* using static memory allocation (nor dynamic memory allocation), but automatic memory allocation. Automatic variables are automatically deallocated at the end of the function (the memory area where they are allocated is known as the stack, because the allocations and deallocations on it have stack semantics). To have the array use static memory allocation you would have to put `static` in front of the definition (note that variables in global or namespace scope always use static memory allocation, though). However, if you make the variable static, you'll find that the compiler doesn't allow to use a non-constant array size any more.

Note that `std::vector` stores its data with dynamic memory allocations instead. For that reason, you can also use a non-constant size even for static `std::vector`s.

Comment: The main reason that it is not allowed is not that there is the alternative of vector. There are deeper reasons, as the fact that the size of an array is part of the type and it must be known at compile time.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: They could have made exceptions to those rules, just as C variable length arrays needed exceptions to the rules of C.

Answer (score 5):

For an array (or any object) declared inside a function, the memory is allocated on entry to the function (typically on the stack) and deallocated when the function returns.  The fact that the function happens to be `main` in this case doesn't affect that.

This:

```
cin >> arraySize;
int arr[arraySize];
```

is a "variable-length array" (VLA).  The thing is, C++ doesn't support VLAs.  C does, starting with the 1999 ISO C standard (C99), but it's not a feature that C++ has adopted.

Your compiler supports VLAs in C++ as an extension.  Using them makes your code non-portable.

(One problem with VLAs is that there's no mechanism for detecting an allocation failure; if `arraySize` is too big, the program's behavior is undefined).

For gcc, compiling with `-pedantic` will produce a warning:

```
warning: ISO C++ forbids variable length array ‘arr’
```

Answer (score 1):

The generated code allocates arraySize bytes on the stack at runtime. Once the function returns, the stack unwinds, including "giving back" the bytes which were allocated on it for the array.

Using new and delete is for allocating space on the heap. The allocated memory lifetime on the heap is independent of any function or method scope - If you allocate space on it in a function, and the function returns, the memory is still allocated and valid.

Answer (score 0):

It's a [Variable Length Array](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html) (supported only in C99 and not in C++). It is allocated on the stack at runtime.

Comment: Is this even valid C++? IIRC the Visual Studio had some erros about this.

Comment: No, it's not dynamic memory allocation. It's automatic memory allocation. @stativ: No, it's not valid C++ (it would be valid C if not surrounded by C++ specific code, however). For C++, it's a non-standard extension of some compilers.

Comment: @celtschk: Is there any *requirement* that the memory be allocated on the stack?  If a particular implementation is capable of allocating it on the stack, that would likely be more efficient than allocating heap memory and later releasing it, but would there be any reason an implementation which couldn't use the stack wouldn't be allowed to use the heap instead?

Comment: @supercat: There is no requirement that it is on the *stack* (or that there is a stack, to begin with). However there is a requirement that it is *automatic* memory allocation (that is, memory that is automatically reclaimed when leaving the function scope), not *dynamic* memory allocation (that is, memory that has to be freed manually, by a call to a memory deallocation function). I'm not sure whether calling `malloc`/`free` by compiler-generated code would be allowed.